# Is it a bad idea to build a webapp that has no user registration?

Tags: web-development, legal, cookie

I always wondered that why all the websites, web applications out there have a whatever kind of user registration, e.g. email, phone, oauth, etc;

I believe that many users don't like email registrations, "First you need to login, in order to submit your post." things. It's simply an opportunity loss for the service provider, right? Why not getting rid of that wall so you can get traffic and active users on your site.

Technically, creating a user account without an email registration is totally possible, using cookie for example. So implementation is not an issue.

So, why? Is there any hidden, underlying, legal or whatever problem when you did something similar to this? Not having user's email is that critical, in this age of any user can pretty easily create an anonymous temporary email address to register?

Comment: It's not opinion based. Don't judge just reading the title. I'm saying "Is there any legal problem when..." Reopen asap please, thank you.

Comment: Legal questions would be out of scope here anyway. But to address your main point there are various applications you can use without login, like games. You can log - to facebook typically - from the game, but it is not mandatory either. But other than that, without specifics on the app (it may be in an area subject to specific laws which in turn make it impossible to work without some kind of authentication), your question is indeed too subjective. And out of scope anyway since not related to running a website really.

Comment: Umm, okay. good point. Well, I just wanted to know the (legal or any) reasons behide the general practice, since "so" many doing so. If the answer to it is "well, it depends" but not "yeah they need to do that, because..." I suppose it's not a serious matter. 
Btw I didn't know that Webmasters is not for website admins/operators but particularly for running a website. I had a vague understanding to the rules here. Now I may want to know an alternative SE site if someone knows any.

Comment: "since "so" many doing so. " They may be doing for other reasons than what you think... Like getting more user data... As for laws, it depends on countries too, so your question is really really too broad/vague. And even if you get some legal related answers, noone should build a business online by taking advices from strangers, you need to consult a relevant lawyer in your jurisdiction.

Comment: Okay, you're right. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was considering creating a web app without user registration recently. The reason I did not proceed with that was that :

> A robot or a malicious user can very easily post thousands of things on my database trough the web app, thus polluting it to an extend I cannot recover from it. A user account to an extend safeguards you from this scenario.

Comment: Well, good point. Where is that citation from, may I know?

Comment: There is no citation. It is the reason I am gonna add user registration.

Comment: I understood. Thanks.